Altair - display lines on a mouseover
I'm trying to display lines (link between centroïd and points) on a map only if I pass my mouse over. But I still don't get why it doesn't work.

Do you know any other function with Altair to do it like this?

Thank you!
The code:
paris = 'https://france-geojson.gregoiredavid.fr/repo/departements/75-paris/communes-75-paris.geojson'
paris = alt.topo_feature(url=paris, feature='geometry')
paris=alt.Chart(paris).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white', 
)


points = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(
    longitude='longitude before departure:Q',
    latitude='latitude before departure:Q',
    size=alt.value(6), 
    tooltip=['latitude before departure:Q', 'longitude before departure:Q']
)

color_scale = alt.Scale(
    domain=[centroids['intervention_count'].min(), centroids['intervention_count'].max()],
    range=["green", "yellow", "red"]
)

select_centroid=alt.selection_point(on="mouseover", 
                                    nearest=True,
                                    fields=["intervention_count"],
                                    empty=False)

centroid_points = alt.Chart(centroids).mark_point().encode(
    longitude='longitude centroid:Q',
    latitude='latitude centroid:Q',
    size=alt.Size('intervention_count:Q', legend=None),
    color=alt.Color('intervention_count:Q', scale=color_scale),
    tooltip=['intervention_count:Q']
).add_params(
    select_centroid
)

connections = alt.Chart(link_centroid_rc).mark_rule(opacity=0.1).encode(
    latitude="latitude before departure:Q",
    longitude="longitude before departure:Q",
    latitude2="latitude centroid:Q",
    longitude2="longitude centroid:Q",
).transform_filter(
    select_centroid
)

chart = (paris + points + centroid_points)
chart = (chart + connections).properties(background="white")

st.altair_chart(chart, use_container_width=True)

I tried to selection_point with mouseover but I don't how to use it with this dataset.

Could you include the definition and a sample of the data of all the variables (e.g. df, and centroids), so that someone can try to run your example in full? Maybe try with intervention_points as a nominal variable also

df is a dataframe from the Paris Fire Brigade: https://paris-fire-brigade.github.io/data-challenge/index.html

I created another dataset centroids which contains information about centroid (principal zone of intervention):#   Column              Non-Null Count  Dtype

0   cluster_label       30 non-null     int32
1   longitude centroid  30 non-null     float64
2   latitude centroid   30 non-null     float64
3   intervention_count  30 non-null     int64

I created another dataset link_centroid_rc which contains information about link between centroid and rescue center: #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype

0   cluster_label               3966 non-null   int32
1   longitude before departure  3966 non-null   float64
2   latitude before departure   3966 non-null   float64
3   longitude centroid          3966 non-null   float64
4   latitude centroid           3966 non-null   float64

Could you please include this in the code in the question? The goal is that someone should be able to just copy/paste your code to be able to reproduce the problem, See [mre] for more details.
